# Change default location of vimrc

Tags: vim

In Vim, is it possible to change the default location of the user vimrc file, i.e., from $HOME/.vimrc to some other location ?

Comment: Please check my answer here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/11879/how-can-put-vimrc-and-viminfo-into-vim-directory

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You must start vim with the command `vim -u ./path/to/your/vimrcfile`

`vim -u NONE` is a good way to start Vim without any plugin or customisation.

See `:help starting.txt` for more information.

Comment: Does the -u option mean that vim will only start with these customizations and all the global customizations from /etc and all will be skipped?

Comment: From starting.txt :`If Vim was started with "-u filename", the file "filename" is used. All following initializations until 4. are skipped.`  The skipped steps include the use of the system wide vimrc. So it is `yes` to your question.

Answer (score 57):

Another solution might be to create a `symlink` to you preferred location. I have my `.vimrc` in `$HOME/.vim/.vimrc` and `symlink` to it. This way I can have it in a git repo and backup it.

Comment: Oh what one would give to work on a platform with such easy access to symlinks.  :)

Comment: @dash-tom-bang This is not common knowledge, but every major OS supports it, *including* Windows (ever since Vista). Try the [mklink](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194(v=ws.10).aspx) utility.

Comment: Also, I just looked up that it is also possible do to pre-vista with an utility called [fsutil](http://serverfault.com/a/7175). Makes sense, since NTFS probably wasn't updated since it's inception.

Comment: win: mklink /j /virtual/folder/_vimrc /real/_vimrc

Answer (score 42):

The `VIMINIT` variable is my preferred method.  The problem with aliasing vim with the `-u` flag is that if vim is opened in some way other than from the shell command your configuration won't get pulled in.  Setting $VIMINIT does not suffer from this drawback.  Check [this](http://tlvince.com/vim-respect-xdg) out for more information.

```
export VIMINIT='source $MYVIMRC'
export MYVIMRC='~/.vim/vimrc'  #or any other location you want
```

Note that Vim normally sets the `MYVIMRC` variable, though I'm not sure exactly what it's used for.  Based on my testing, using `VIMINIT` in this fashion will result in it not being automatically set on startup as it would normally be.  This is why I'm setting it myself.

This works for neovim too!

Comment: This works for me on both Ubuntu and Cygwin. I also don't see the need for `MYVIMRC` here - e.g. `export VIMINIT='source ~/.vim/vimrc'` works on my small test. It might bite me later though, so I'll use it for now anyway.

Comment: This was not enought for autoloading my `pathogen.vim`; I had to `set runtimepath` as well, as per [this](https://superuser.com/questions/413942/use-another-users-vimrc-and-vim#comment1169304_557073) comment.

Answer (score 18):

On Windows, I have the `_vimrc` that's in my home directory contain one line, `source c:\path\to\my.vimrc`.

I have not yet worked out a good way to move the entirety of my vimfiles folder, but that's less critical as it's all stuff I've installed from elsewhere.  I.e., it'd be easy to restore if I lost it.  (I know that I can change `runtimepath` but my problem is more coming up with a "good" way to do so.)

**Update**

After six years I extended slightly from what I mention in the comments below; as I put stuff into 'after' and wanted to just keep `rtp` clean I got something that has been solid for a while now. Today in my `%USERPROFILE%\_vimrc` I do hardcode the actual paths to things and it changes on every machine I use (and I basically do the same thing on *nix) but this gets copied around mostly-manually when setting up a new PC. I also have a version which I can use to launch Vim on another connected machine on the network, e.g. a co-worker's machine, so I get my config and all that, but the gist is:

```
set runtimepath^=E:/dotfiles/vim
set runtimepath+=E:/dotfiles/vim/after
set runtimepath-=~/vimfiles
set runtimepath-=~/vimfiles/after
runtime vimrc
```

and then `%USERPROFILE%\_gvimrc` just has one line:

```
runtime gvimrc
```

(Both `vimrc` and `gvimrc` are in the `/dotfiles/vim` folder and also [on Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/plunket/dotfiles/src).)

Comment: I have since just decided to do `set runtimepath^=d:\path\to\vimfiles` which unfortunately hardcodes the location of those files but now at least I can keep them in source control.  As it turns out, the more I use Vim, the more customization I want for my setup.

Comment: This is definitely the most pain-free approach for this issue

Comment: This is the best solution after my opinion. I would say to add this to the ~/.bash_profile-file: alias vim="/PATH/TO/VIM-DIR/vim -S ~/PATH/TO/VIMRC-DIR/.vimrc" And the path to vim can be found by writing which vim (to see which vim is being used).

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, after I realized that the line cannot be: source "c:\path\to\my.vimrc" (AKA must not use quotation marks)

Answer (score 4):

I see two options, depending on your needs.

1. Have ~/.vimrc import the other location
2. create an alias in your bashrc alias vim="vim -u otherlocation"

Comment: How does one do the first of these things?

Answer (score 2):

I edited

```
C:\Program Files\Vim\_vimrc
```

and changed both the runtimepath and sourced my own .vimrc.

I also use these settings in Cygwin (and have them version controlled). So it's this in practice (added at the bottom of the _vimrc file):

```
let &runtimepath = 'C:\cygwin\home\cygwinaccount\.vim,' . &runtimepath
source C:\cygwin\home\cygwinaccount\.vimrc
```

Bliss ! :)

Answer (score 2):

In linux:
You can edit `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` startup script and add the following lines to change the default location of .vimrc file

```
export VIMINIT='source $MYVIMRC'
export MYVIMRC='~/.vim/.vimrc'  # Note the . (dot) before vimrc. If that is what you have called it.
```

Answer (score 2):

I feel like the simplest solution is to just have a single line in `~/.vimrc` that loads the vimrc from the other location, i.e.:

```
source PATH/TO/OTHER/LOCATION/.vimrc
```