# Location of _vimrc

Tags: vim, vi

My customized `_vimrc` file is saved at `$HOME` which is here:

> M:_vimrc

Could I move `_vimrc` to say the following location and still have gvim find it ok?

> M:\UsefulDirectoryName_vimrc

Comment: Yes you can :) This question answers the question for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109667/change-default-location-of-vimrc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vim will only find your `_vimrc` if it's at one of these two locations:

```
$HOME/_vimrc
$VIM/_vimrc
```

If you want to use a different location you'll have to tell Vim where your `_vimrc` is. You can:

- launch Vim with this command, `vim -u /path/to/_vimrc`
- add this line to `$HOME/_vimrc`, `source /path/to/_vimrc`

Comment: romainl - you are the omnipresent vimmer - +1 thanks

Comment: `:s/omnipresent/bored`

Comment: but if I use your method I will still need to keep `$HOME/_vimrc` but it will only have one line in it `source /path/to/_vimrc` and the actual rc that does all the work will be at `/path/to/_vimrc` ?

Comment: Yes. That's basically what I do to keep my `~/.vim` directory under version control with my "real" vimrc inside.

Comment: @romainl don't shake my beliefs you are omnipresent!

Comment: @PeterRincker ...try it out; type a request for vim into SO and he appears - like a hotline to romainl - starting to think his name might be Bram

Comment: When I learned of the #vim IRC channel earlier this year, I headed into my client to check it out, and the first message that popped up was romainl. He *is* omnipresent.

Comment: Incidentally, I also learned about #vim not long ago. And no, I'm not Bram, far from it.

Comment: @romainl omnipresent(ish) ...[this has been left alone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16802259/vim-not-finding-the-end-of-the-sql-statement)

Answer (score 3):

`:help vimrc` says

```
    Recommended place for your personal initializations:
    Unix            $HOME/.vimrc
    OS/2            $HOME/.vimrc or $VIM/.vimrc (or _vimrc)
    MS-DOS and Win32    $HOME/_vimrc or $VIM/_vimrc
    Amiga           s:.vimrc or $VIM/.vimrc
```

So, you can set `$VIM` to `UsefulDirectoryName` and give it a try.

Comment: +1 ah - ok - so $HOME is gerneric to my pc - but I'm able to configure $VIM ?